# What is the purpose of "Reset All Stats"?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I noticed in the Prestige Shop there is an option for 10th level prestige where you can reset all stats. What is the purpose of it? The only use I could think of is using it after you've beat the multiplayer and just feel like beating it again for the hell of it.

Answer (score 2):

People care a lot about their stats, whether its accuracy, kill/death, win/loss, or highest kill streak.  In the previous Call of Duties people often struggled with trying a new gun and getting good at it vs using a gun your already good with and helping your kill/death.

By allowing the ability to reset, people can take the game a little less seriously.  They can experiment with guns and play styles they previously would never try knowing they can always reset and try again. In the end allowing players reset their stats it relieves a lot of stress from players over concern about their stats, and lets them start over from scratch enjoying that initial "unlock excitement" that a fresh account gives.

Comment: But it's not unlocked til 10th prestige! And it also resets your prestige level according to the [their site](http://www.themodernwarfare3.com/mw3/prestige-shop/).

Comment: @Earlz I'm not sure thats true.  You get a prestige token each prestige (apart from going prestige in the other games).  I can check when I get home but I'm pretty sure you can spend the token to reset your stats at any prestige level.

Comment: @Earlz It looks like I was mistaken, it isn't unlockable until 10th prestige, but the fresh stats and 'doing it all again' are the undoubtable draw.

Comment: Are you sure that it resets your level or only your stats like your kill/death ratio and kill and death counts? Or does it reset your level and everything else?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the intent is to give you something to do once you've hit the max level on the 10th prestige.

The goal with this Modern Warfare iteration seems to be to keep you playing all year long - they've taken a lot of the pain out of Prestige mode with Prestige Tokens, and they're pushing incremental content monthly with CoD: Elite Premium.  I think this is just one more way to convince people to keep playing even after they top out the Prestige ladder.

I have to assume there's some custom Emblem/Title so that you can tell the world that you've played the game so long you've wrapped it completely around again, but I'll probably never confirm this theory :)

Comment: I'm sure we'll find out if there is such a title/emblem in a few weeks. There are some hardcore nerds out there :)

Answer (score 1):

It resets everything.

I thought it would just be kill/death and win/loss ratios not prestige level, but I spent hours and days to get to final prestige to reset stats and it started me back at level 1 with no special distinction to say I made it all the way already.

Answer (score 1):

You get nothing but a new start at level 1. I did it today and lost everything including your rank emblems and titles. The only thing I didn't like about the reset is there is no way to prove it unless you have elite or all your friends watching you like I did and even then people don't always think you are for real until you show them. It took me 3 weeks to hit 10th, not going to be that hard to get back with a better k/d.

Answer (score -2):

So, you're saying that you received no special emblem or title for going through 10 prestiges and resetting your stats?

There are a couple of emblems that I saw on [this website](http://www.imodernwarfare3.com/modern-warfare-3-emblems-and-how-to-earn-them/) (and 1 in-game) that I figured you might get if you reset.

Row 8 (last emblem)
Row 9 (first 2)
4th Row from the bottom (pretty much the entire row)
3rd Row from the bottom (3rd, 4th, 5th, & 6th emblem)